# Как использовать миксины в React.js ES6/7?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Здравствуйте.
Такой вопрос: до написания на синтаксисе ES6 писал так:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
mixins: [
    Reflux.listenTo(ListStore, 'onChangeList')
]
...
```

А как быть с переходом на ES6, ведь если не ошибаюсь то там миксины исключили?

Answer (score 1):

При использовании классов ES2015(ES6) примеси использовать [нельзя](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-mixins):

> Unfortunately ES6 launched without any mixin support. Therefore, there is no support for mixins when you use React with ES6 classes.

Как вариант, вы все еще можете использовать синтаксис `React.createClass`.

Comment: а как быть тогда с Reflux ? Там же миксины используют? как их заменить?

Comment: Используйте `React.createClass`. Вас же никто не заставляет использовать синтаксис ES6 :)

Comment: да столько уже написал, теперь переписывать обратно не хочется....

Comment: С Rectiflux я вам не помощник -- не работал с ним.

Comment: может вы знаете: я тут наткнулся на Falcor, это может быть заменой Reflux или Flux? может вы использовали эту технологию и она лучше ого же Рефлакса или Флакса?

Comment: https://netflix.github.io/falcor/starter/what-is-falcor.html

Comment: Думаю, что вам лучше задать отдельный вопрос по reflux